# XML to JSON proxy server not fetching XML feed

Tags: javascript, php, json, proxy

I am trying to display posts from a wordpress blog onto a remote website using an RSS feed provided by wordpress. But, of course, I am having to deal with trying to get around CORS. Therefore, I am now trying to create an XML to JSON proxy server in PHP and am using [this resource as a guide](http://www.sitepoint.com/php-xml-to-json-proxy/).

> Here's how I have my HTML set up for the output:

```
<div id="output"></div>
```

> The ajax to call the PHP proxy:

```
// my test XML feed with only one post for now
var url = "http://www.intecllc.net/wp/feed/";

// AJAX request
var xhr = (window.XMLHttpRequest ? new XMLHttpRequest() : new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"));
xhr.onreadystatechange = XHRhandler;
xhr.open("GET", "xmlproxy.php?url=" + escape(url), true);
xhr.send(null);

// handle response
function XHRhandler() {
    if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
        // parse response as JSON
        var json;
        if (JSON && JSON.parse) {
            json = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
        }
        else {
            eval("var json = " + xhr.responseText);
        }
        Display(json);
        xhr = null;
    }
}

// display post(s)
function Display(data) {
    var output = document.getElementById("output");
    Show("Data from URL: "+url);

    if (data && data.item) {
        if (data.item.length) {
            // multiple statuses
            for (var i=0, sl=data.item.length; i < sl; i++) {
                Show(data.item[i]);
            }
        }
        else {
            // single status
            Show(data.item);
        }
    }

    // display item
    function Show(item) {
        if (typeof item != "string") {
            item = item.title + ": " + item.description;
        }
        var p = document.createElement("p");
        p.appendChild(document.createTextNode(item));
        output.appendChild(p);
    }
}
```

> The PHP proxy code (The proxy will fetch the contents of the passed
>   URL as a string, parse it as XML and convert it to JSON. The JSON
>   string will be returned to the calling JavaScript process.):

```
<?php 

ini_set('display_errors', false);
set_exception_handler('ReturnError');
$r = '';
$url = (isset($_GET['url']) ? $_GET['url'] : null);

if ($url) {
    // fetch XML
    $c = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($c, array(
        CURLOPT_URL => $url,
        CURLOPT_HEADER => false,
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 10,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true
    ));
    $r = curl_exec($c);
    curl_close($c);
}

if ($r) {
    // XML to JSON
    echo json_encode(new SimpleXMLElement($r));
}
else {
    // nothing returned?
    ReturnError();
}

// return JSON error flag
function ReturnError() {
    echo '{"error":true}';
}
```

**Unfortunately, it's not grabbing the feed and parsing it. Can someone help me troubleshoot? Thank you.**

Comment: I would start by trying a library handling XHR Requests (jQuery will do just fine). XHR is implemented sooo differently across browsers.

Comment: try `var_dump($r);` just after ` $r = curl_exec($c);`

Comment: I thought JavaScript does not parse json by default. Am I wrong here? In the beginning of your `Display(data)` do a console.log(data). What is the output in developer console?

Comment: what is the result of your ajax call?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your output JSON is not what you are expecting.
I get the following JSON from the same feed

```
{
    "@attributes": {
        "version": "2.0"
    },
    "channel": {
        "title": "InTec, LLC",
        "link": "http://www.intecllc.net/wp",
        "description": "tagline here",
        "lastBuildDate": "Fri, 04 Mar 2016 17:47:52 +0000",
        "language": "en-US",
        "generator": "http://wordpress.org/?v=4.2.7",
        "item": {
            "title": "InTec Welcomes New Director of Contracts",
            "link": "http://www.intecllc.net/wp/intec-welcomes-new-director-of-contracts/",
            "comments": "http://www.intecllc.net/wp/intec-welcomes-new-director-of-contracts/#comments",
            "pubDate": "Fri, 04 Mar 2016 17:47:52 +0000",
            "category": {},
            "guid": "http://www.intecllc.net/wp/?p=101",
            "description": {}
        }
    }
}
```

Here we can clearly see that there is no key named `item` immediately at the root element hence your `if` condition `if (data && data.item) {` cannot be satisfied.

here's a modified javascript,

```
    // my test XML feed with only one post for now
    var url = "http://www.intecllc.net/wp/feed/";

    // AJAX request
    var xhr = (window.XMLHttpRequest ? new XMLHttpRequest() : new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"));
    xhr.onreadystatechange = XHRhandler;
    xhr.open("GET", "index.php?url=" + escape(url), true);
    xhr.send(null);

    // handle response
    function XHRhandler() {
        if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
            // parse response as JSON
            var json;
            if (JSON && JSON.parse) {
                json = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
            } else {
                eval("var json = " + xhr.responseText);
            }
            Display(json);
            xhr = null;
        }
    }

    // display post(s)
    function Display(data) {
        var output = document.getElementById("output");
        Show("Data from URL: " + url);

        if (data && data.channel.item) {
            if (data.channel.item.length) {
                // multiple statuses
                for (var i = 0, sl = data.channel.item.length; i < sl; i++) {
                    Show(data.channel.item[i]);
                }
            } else {
                // single status
                Show(data.channel.item);
            }
        }

        // display item
        function Show(item) {
            if (typeof item != "string") {
                item = item.title + ": " + item.description;
            }
            var p = document.createElement("p");
            p.appendChild(document.createTextNode(item));
            output.appendChild(p);
        }
    }
```

Hope this is what you are looking for

Also, You need to replace the following in yout PHP code

```
echo json_encode(new SimpleXMLElement($r));
```

with

```
echo json_encode(simplexml_load_string($r, 'SimpleXMLElement', LIBXML_NOCDATA));
```

This will better handle `<![CDATA[` nodes

Comment: Thank you. I will check it and report back!

Comment: I'm using Chrome and in my devconsole I'm seeing that my Get request is like so: GET "https://mydomainhere.com/xmlproxy.php?url=https%3A//blogs.myotherdomainhere.com/blogs/%3Ffeed%3Drss2". Then on next line in console says: Uncaught TypeError: Cannaot read property 'item' of undefined.

Comment: Can you verify that your php script output is same as I have mentioned above? (first code block)

Comment: Verified the php script output is same as mentioned. When doing a console.log(data) I get in console: Object{error: true}.

Comment: If your php script outputs the same data as I have mentioned, you should get the same data in `console.log(data)`because its essentially the same. Try `console.log(json)` right before `Display(json);`

Comment: can you show us a link where you are running this script?

Comment: Object {error:true} for console.log(json), too. OK, will investigate and try to replicate at home. Thanks. I'm behind firewall right now.

Comment: Just to confirm, that the line `xhr.open("GET", "index.php?url=" + escape(url), true);` is an index.php file that contains the proxy code?

Comment: Correct. I have set up your php script in index.php

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108845/discussion-between-redshift-and-rohit-agre).

Comment: So it turns out it's a PKI issue at my company and so this method will not work. However, thanks for your time and I will mark it as solved.